# Create tone with adjustable frequency/amplitude

Tags: manipulate, sound, signal-processing

How can I play a tone and adjust its frequency and amplitude?

As an example, say I wanted to play a `SquareWave` with a slider for frequency and amplitude. Using a `Manipulate`. I have tried the following:

- Using `Manipulate` the `Play` object reloads each time the sliders are adjusted, so the tone stops when adjusted; and it takes a long time to evaluate and render said object.

  ```
  Manipulate[Play[SquareWave[{-a,a}, f t], {t,0,10}], {{a,1}, 0, 10}, {{f,440}, 20, 20000}]
  ```
- Using `Dynamic` on the `Play` object reevaluates like `Manipulate`, using it at any position inside the `Play` causes the object to stop rendering entirely (`Sound:ssnm`), apparently failing to find an amplitude scale factor.

  ```
  Dynamic @ Play[SquareWave[{-a,a}, f t], {t,0,10}]
  Play[Dynamic @ SquareWave[{-a,a}, f t], {t,0,10}]
  Play[SquareWave[Dynamic@{-a,a}, t Dynamic@f], {t,0,10}]
  ```